# divs in ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

i cant not use functions in a select loaded in a div with ajax in jQuery , any help? please This is the jQuery  code

```
$("#cbo_sede").change(function () {
    var sede = document.getElementById("cbo_sede").value;
    var region = document.getElementById("cbo_region").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "salon.php",
        data: 'region=' + region + '&sede=' + sede,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div_salon").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Read [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("change","#cbo_sede",function(){ ..code here.. });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```